# How to Retrieve the password from asp.net membership provider from DB

Tags: asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership

I want to retreive users passwords from the db , I tried something like this :

```
SELECT password, passwordformat, passwordsalt
FROM aspnet_membership am
INNER JOIN aspnet_users au
    ON (au.userid = am.userid)
INNER JOIN aspnet_applications aa
    ON (au.applicationId = aa.applicationid)
 WHERE au.username = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
AND aa.ApplicationId = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
```

But the query returns the hashed password , Is there any way i can get the original password not the hashed one. Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is hashed you cannot retrieve it but you can recover it. Do not invent the wheel and use e.g. [PasswordRecovery Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178335.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

If you by all means want to avoid using the PasswordRecovery control and want to implement this functionality by yourself you still do not need to implement your own queries to `aspnet_db`. There are plenty of built in methods for most of security issues in the Membership API.

You can use something like follows to reset the password:

```
 string username = "user";
 string password = "pass@word";
 MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);
 mu.ChangePassword(mu.ResetPassword(), password);
```

This should work in case you store hashed passwords and disable q&a. In case you want q&a be enabled you can use a workaround described [here](http://peterkellner.net/2007/02/15/resetpasswordaspnet/).

Comment: can i change it after recovering

Comment: PasswordRecoveryControl uses q&A and I am not using secret question and answer in my scenario , i just want to reset the password , then the user can login and change the password

Comment: If the user is recovering the hashed password using the PasswordRecovery control your application will send them a new automatically created password. By default, ASP.NET hashes passwords using a non-reversible encryption scheme, so a new password is sent to the user. You can configure your membership provider to encrypt passwords, in which case your application will send users either their current password.

Comment: The PasswordRecovery control displays the Question view only when the membership provider defined in the MembershipProvider property supports password question and answer. May be it is worth to look at this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/recovering-and-changing-passwords-cs)

Answer (score 1):

**No you can't!!**
Its a hashed not encrypted

**You should not store passwords as plain text**

Comment: I am not saving the password as a plain text , it is saved as hash nd salt value

Comment: how to reset it and then give user control to change it afterwards

Comment: @Mr you can customize the default provider behavior. Implement your own method to reset the password